# regex-group(last()) in XSLT

Tags: regex, xslt-2.0, xslt-3.0, xslkey

Working on linking of some text in input with analyze-string but not able to retrive `regex-group(last())` in script.

You can check transform at https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/bnnZVG

As you see, current output

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<TEST>
    <P>Check <Link ID="ID0001">AbC,2013</Link>AbC,2013Marking</P>
    <P>Check <Link ID="ID0001">ABc, 2013</Link>ABc, 2013Marking</P>
    <P>Check <Link ID="ID0001">ABC 2013</Link>ABC 2013Marking</P>
    <P>Check <Link ID="ID0001">ABC</Link>ABCMarking</P>
    <P>Check <Link ID="ID0002">BCA,2013</Link>BCA,2013Marking</P>
    <P>Check <Link ID="ID0002">bcA, 2013</Link>bcA, 2013Marking</P>
    <P>Check <Link ID="ID0002">BCa 2013</Link>BCa 2013Marking</P>
    <P>Check <Link ID="ID0002">bcA</Link>bcAMarking</P>
</TEST>
```

but expected output is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<TEST>
    <P>Check <Link ID="ID0001">AbC,2013</Link> Marking</P>
    <P>Check <Link ID="ID0001">ABc, 2013</Link> Marking</P>
    <P>Check <Link ID="ID0001">ABC 2013</Link> Marking</P>
    <P>Check <Link ID="ID0001">ABC</Link> Marking</P>
    <P>Check <Link ID="ID0002">BCA,2013</Link> Marking</P>
    <P>Check <Link ID="ID0002">bcA, 2013</Link> Marking</P>
    <P>Check <Link ID="ID0002">BCa 2013</Link> Marking</P>
    <P>Check <Link ID="ID0002">bcA</Link> Marking</P>
</TEST>
```

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which value do you expect from calling `last()` inside of `xsl:analyze-string`? If you look at the last paragraph in https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-30/#element-analyze-string it says:

> A matching substring is processed using the xsl:matching-substring
>   element, a non-matching substring using the xsl:non-matching-substring
>   element. Each of these elements takes a sequence constructor as its
>   content. If the element is absent, the effect is the same as if it
>   were present with empty content. In processing each substring, the
>   contents of the substring will be the context item (as a value of type
>   xs:string); the position of the substring within the sequence of
>   matching and non-matching substrings will be the context position; and
>   the number of matching and non-matching substrings will be the context
>   size.

So as `last()` returns the context size it should be equal to the number of matching and non-matching substrings.

I realize this is not quite an answer but it is too long to be used as a comment. You might also want to edit your question and tell us what the XSLT you have linked to is supposed to achieve in plain words, then we might be able to help suggest an appropriate XSLT solution.

Also note that XSLT 3 with XPath 3 has an `analyze-string` function which returns an XML structure with the matches and groups so processing/consuming that might help you to extract the contents you want:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions"
    exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
    version="3.0">

    <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>

    <xsl:key name="testkey" match="link" use="linkname"/>

    <xsl:variable name="testcheck">
        <link name="ID0001">
            <linkname>abc, 2013</linkname>
            <linkname>abc</linkname>
        </link>
        <link name="ID0002">
            <linkname>bca, 2013</linkname>
            <linkname>bca</linkname>
        </link>
    </xsl:variable>

    <xsl:variable name="test">
        <xsl:text>(</xsl:text>
        <xsl:for-each select="$testcheck//linkname">
            <xsl:if test="position() ne 1"><xsl:text>|</xsl:text></xsl:if>
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </xsl:for-each>
        <xsl:text>)</xsl:text>
    </xsl:variable>

    <xsl:variable name="regex" as="xs:string"
      select="concat('(^|\W)', replace($test, ', ([0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9])', '(, $1|,$1| $1)?'), '($|\W)')"/>

    <xsl:template match="text()[matches(., $regex, 'i')]">
         <xsl:apply-templates select="analyze-string(., $regex, 'i')" mode="extract"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:mode name="extract" on-no-match="text-only-copy"/>

    <xsl:template match="fn:match/fn:group[@nr = 2]" mode="extract">
        <Link ID="{$testcheck//key('testkey', lower-case(replace(current(), '(, |,| )([0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9])', ', $2')))/@name}">
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </Link>          
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/bnnZVG/2 gives

```
<TEST>
    <P>Check <Link ID="ID0001">AbC,2013</Link> Marking</P>
    <P>Check <Link ID="ID0001">ABc, 2013</Link> Marking</P>
    <P>Check <Link ID="ID0001">ABC 2013</Link> Marking</P>
    <P>Check <Link ID="ID0001">ABC</Link> Marking</P>
    <P>Check <Link ID="ID0002">BCA,2013</Link> Marking</P>
    <P>Check <Link ID="ID0002">bcA, 2013</Link> Marking</P>
    <P>Check <Link ID="ID0002">BCa 2013</Link> Marking</P>
    <P>Check <Link ID="ID0002">bcA</Link> Marking</P>
</TEST>
```

Comment: Hi @Martin, Actually i have past a complex regex in analyze-string, and i know that what is in `regex-group(1)` and `regex-group(2)`, but not able to find the last regex-group number to fetch that value in matching-substring. as you see in example that in analyze string regex is consist of 6 group and counting is increased when added extra entry.